# How to: Prevent opening new browser tabs in Electron

Tags: electron

I am trying to prevent links that would normally open in a new tab from opening at all.

I don't mind if it's prevents the link from working, I just need to stop the event or close the tab as soon as it tries to open.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the links are opening in a new window, not in a new tab.

This snippet will prevent opening link in new window.

```js
win.webContents.on('new-window', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

*win is the window object of Electron

Answer (score 1):

the 'new-window' event is deprecated & was removed as of electron 22.  https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/breaking-changes

to achieve the same result past electron 22, use

```
win.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler(() => {
  return { action: "deny" };
});
```

where win is your instance of browser window created with

```
const win = new BrowserWindow({...})
```

for more detail see https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentssetwindowopenhandlerhandler